# Hibernate Search spatial facet query works first 5 times then only returns the 5th result

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I have an index of vehicles for sale at various geographic locations and I’m looking to find all the distinct manufacturers with the number of cars they have available within a radius at a specific location and under a specific price.

I have written the query code which seems to work perfectly for the first 5 attempts then the results seem to ‘stick’ on the 5th query’s latitude, longitude and radius. Changing the price element changes the results but only in that 5th query's location and radius.

I’m not sure if I have to ‘flush’ anything or this is a configuration issue but it seems odd that the query just stops working after 5 attempts. I’m bemused and cannot find this issue replicated online so any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the query…

```
private List<VehicleManufacturer> getManufacturers( double valuation , double latitude , double longitude, int radius  ) throws Exception {

    long startTIme = new Date().getTime() ;

    List<VehicleManufacturer> returnedManufacturers = new ArrayList<VehicleManufacturer> () ;

    FullTextEntityManager manufacturerFullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);     
    QueryBuilder manufacturerBuilder = manufacturerFullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(AvailableVehicle.class).get() ;

    // CREATE SPATIAL AND TOP PRICE FULL TEXT QUERY
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query manufacturingSpatialQuery = manufacturerBuilder.spatial().within( radius , Unit.KM ).ofLatitude( latitude ).andLongitude( longitude ).createQuery();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query manufacturingValuationRoof = NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange("valuation", 0d , valuation , true, true); 
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query manufacturingValuationAndSpatialQuery =  manufacturerBuilder.bool().must(manufacturingValuationRoof).must(manufacturingSpatialQuery).createQuery() ;         
    FullTextQuery manufacturingFullTextQuery = manufacturerFullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(manufacturingValuationAndSpatialQuery,  AvailableVehicle.class);

    // FACET  REQUEST
    FacetingRequest manufacturingFacetingRequest = manufacturerBuilder.facet().name( "manufacturerFaceting"  ).onField("manufacturer").discrete().orderedBy( FacetSortOrder.FIELD_VALUE ).includeZeroCounts(false).createFacetingRequest(); 

    FacetManager facetManager = manufacturingFullTextQuery.getFacetManager();
    facetManager.enableFaceting(manufacturingFacetingRequest);       
    List<Facet> facets = facetManager.getFacets( "manufacturerFaceting" );

    for (Facet manuacturingFacet : facets) {
        VehicleManufacturer manufacturer = new VehicleManufacturer( manuacturingFacet.getValue() , manuacturingFacet.getCount() ) ;
        returnedManufacturers.add( manufacturer ) ;         
    }

    System.out.println( "MANUFACTURERS count: "  + returnedManufacturers.size() + "  time: " + ( new Date().getTime() - startTIme )  + "ms  latitude:" +  latitude + "  longitude: " + longitude  + "  radius: " + radius  ) ;

    return returnedManufacturers ;      
}
```

...and here is the abridged indexed object class…

```
@Entity
@Indexed( index="AvailableVehicle"  )
@Spatial(spatialMode = SpatialMode.RANGE )
@Table(name = "car_available_vehicle")
public class AvailableVehicle  implements Coordinates {

@Id     
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID" )
private int id ;

@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn( name="VEHICLE_ID" )
private Vehicle vehicle ;

@Facet()
@Column(name = "MANUFACTURER" )
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
private String manufacturer ;

@Facet()
@Column(name = "MODEL" )
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
private String model ;

@Column(name = "LONGITUDE" )    
private Double longitude ;

@Column(name = "LATITUDE" )     
private Double latitude ;

@Column(name = "PRICE" )
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
@NumericField( forField="price" )
private double price ;

@Column(name = "VALUATION" )
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
@NumericField( forField="valuation" )
private double valuation ;
```

.. and here are the hibernate maven dependencies…

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a guess, but you may be hitting [HSEARCH-2691](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2691). The bug was fixed in Hibernate Search version `5.7.1.Final`; maybe you could try that version?

Comment: Many thanks, going up to 5.7.1 solved the problem so it looks pretty likely the issue was as a result of that bug. I stupidly discounted going up a version as I assumed the issue would be with me. Cheers.